# Alternative to punching bag

Tags: equipment, training, boxing

I'm not entirely sure this question fits here, but here we go.

I've started with boxing/kickboxen a bit over a year ago. Now I'm looking for a way to train at home. Especially with a punching bag or something similar to conditions my body for the impact of punching amd kicking,  so shadowboxing is not really suited.

The issue is that I live in an apartment and I don't have a lot of space for anything so I'm looking for a space saving or easily storable solution.

Comment: Don't you have a pillar to train like Tong Po?

Comment: Nope my apartment isn't that fancy

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old, but one option you have is to use an inflatable punching bag. That way you can blow it up when you need it and deflate it when you are done. They can be purchased on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RHKQ8S7) relatively cheaply.